# Custom Slider in Flutter square

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I'm having problems creating a custom slider on flutter. The image is the following one:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to customize the shapes of `Theme.sliderTheme.thumbShape` and `Theme.sliderTheme.trackShape`.

Check the screenshot and the [live demo on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=9041b42cb9042d30353b48ec95f1b240):

[image: Screenshot]

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double sliderValue = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 115, 0),
          child: Theme(
            data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
              sliderTheme: SliderThemeData(
                thumbShape: SquareSliderComponentShape(),
                trackShape: MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape(),
              ),
            ),
            child: Slider(
              onChanged: (value) => setState(() => sliderValue = value),
              value: sliderValue,
              min: 0,
              max: 100,
              activeColor: Colors.black,
              inactiveColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 209, 138),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SquareSliderComponentShape extends SliderComponentShape {
  @override
  Size getPreferredSize(bool isEnabled, bool isDiscrete) {
    return const Size(20, 30);
  }

  @override
  void paint(PaintingContext context, Offset center,
      {required Animation<double> activationAnimation,
      required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
      required bool isDiscrete,
      required TextPainter labelPainter,
      required RenderBox parentBox,
      required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
      required TextDirection textDirection,
      required double value,
      required double textScaleFactor,
      required Size sizeWithOverflow}) {
    final Canvas canvas = context.canvas;
    canvas.drawShadow(
        Path()
          ..addRRect(RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
            Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 24, height: 30),
            const Radius.circular(4),
          )),
        Colors.black,
        5,
        false);
    canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromRectAndRadius(
        Rect.fromCenter(center: center, width: 20, height: 30),
        const Radius.circular(4),
      ),
      Paint()..color = Colors.amber,
    );
  }
}

class MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape extends SliderTrackShape
    with BaseSliderTrackShape {
  const MyRoundedRectSliderTrackShape();

  @override
  void paint(
    PaintingContext context,
    Offset offset, {
    required RenderBox parentBox,
    required SliderThemeData sliderTheme,
    required Animation<double> enableAnimation,
    required TextDirection textDirection,
    required Offset thumbCenter,
    bool isDiscrete = false,
    bool isEnabled = false,
    double additionalTrackHeight = 10,
  }) {
    if (sliderTheme.trackHeight == null || sliderTheme.trackHeight! <= 0) {
      return;
    }

    final ColorTween activeTrackColorTween = ColorTween(
        begin: sliderTheme.disabledActiveTrackColor,
        end: sliderTheme.activeTrackColor);
    final ColorTween inactiveTrackColorTween = ColorTween(
        begin: sliderTheme.disabledInactiveTrackColor,
        end: sliderTheme.inactiveTrackColor);
    final Paint activePaint = Paint()
      ..color = activeTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;
    final Paint inactivePaint = Paint()
      ..color = inactiveTrackColorTween.evaluate(enableAnimation)!;
    final Paint leftTrackPaint;
    final Paint rightTrackPaint;
    switch (textDirection) {
      case TextDirection.ltr:
        leftTrackPaint = activePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        break;
      case TextDirection.rtl:
        leftTrackPaint = inactivePaint;
        rightTrackPaint = activePaint;
        break;
    }

    final Rect trackRect = getPreferredRect(
      parentBox: parentBox,
      offset: offset,
      sliderTheme: sliderTheme,
      isEnabled: isEnabled,
      isDiscrete: isDiscrete,
    );
    final Radius activeTrackRadius =
        Radius.circular((trackRect.height + additionalTrackHeight) / 2);

    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
        trackRect.left,
        trackRect.top - (additionalTrackHeight / 2),
        thumbCenter.dx,
        trackRect.bottom + (additionalTrackHeight / 2),
        topLeft: activeTrackRadius,
        bottomLeft: activeTrackRadius,
      ),
      leftTrackPaint,
    );
    context.canvas.drawRRect(
      RRect.fromLTRBAndCorners(
        thumbCenter.dx,
        trackRect.top - (additionalTrackHeight / 2),
        trackRect.right,
        trackRect.bottom + (additionalTrackHeight / 2),
        topRight: activeTrackRadius,
        bottomRight: activeTrackRadius,
      ),
      rightTrackPaint,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, bro you help me I read your code and I understand now,